# How to copy a formula from one gsheet to another using python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm not sure if this is possible. I have tons of spreadsheet, and the formulas need to be updated. How do I copy a formula from one cell or a group of cells to another? I've used `gspread` and it seems it can only do values. I need python to basically paste formulas on hundreds of sheets for me, without me opening each individually and copy and pasting the formulas.

Does anybody have a generic solution for copying and pasting formulas? This is pretty important, you would think someone can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update 19 July 2018:

Here's how you do it:

```
# Get the formula value from the souce cell:
formula = wks.acell('A2', value_render_option='FORMULA').value

# Update the target cell with formula:
wks.update_acell('B3', formula)
```

(this works since gspread 3.0.0 which uses Sheets API v4.)

#### Original answer below:

To access a formula value, you need to use the `input_value` attribute of a cell object.

Here's an example. (I'm skipping the initialization step. Let's assume you've already opened a spreadsheet and `wks` is referring to you [worksheet object](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#gspread.Worksheet).)

```
# To copy a formula from a single cell (say, A2) to another cell (B3)
# use the input_value property
formula = wks.acell('A2').input_value

# then paste the value to a new cell
wks.update_acell('B3', formula)
```

For a group of cells, you'd want to use a `wks.range()` method to get cell objects. Then you can get formula values via `input_value` as in the code above. See [the example](https://github.com/burnash/gspread#updating-cells) on the GitHub.

Comment: What version of API does `gspread` use? I see that `pygsheets` is using API v4. What is `gspread` using and what do you plan to do? What's the roadmap?

Comment: Presently, it's v3, but I'm working on upgrading the library to v4. It's already using v4 for new features (e.g. sharing a spreadsheet.)

Comment: doesn't work. value of `formula` becomes `None` even when there is a formula at `A2`.

Comment: use `wks.acell('A2', value_render_option='FORMULA').value` instead. `input_value` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This solution was also helpful for me in writing formulas to google sheet cells: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50648449/764307