# Updating cell values with formulas results in apostrophe prefixes with Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using gspread and the Google Sheets API to update cell values, setting `cell.value` equal to a string of a specific formula.

Example code:

```
# Calculates sum of cells in current row from column B to H
G_SHEETS_ROW_SUM_COMMAND = '''=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",ROW(),":H",ROW())))'''

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = G_SHEETS_ROW_SUM_COMMAND
```

When my spreadsheet is populated, however, my command becomes prefixed with an apostrophe (`'`). This is presumably to keep the cell from being interpreted as a formula, but that's exactly what I'd like it to do.

Here's an example from my spreadsheet:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this apostrophe automatically?

I've looked into value rendering options and input_value, though these options seem to be unavailable for writing to sheets.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't specify a value input option when I updated my cells. In my case, the solution looks like this:

```py
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

Note the `value_input_option` flag, it must be set to `'USER_ENTERED'` so that cells are updated just as if they were entered in the Google Sheets UI.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, but was looking to just update a single cell using a formula. I found a couple of ways to do it:

```py
# 'A1' notation
worksheet.update('A1', 7)
# raw=False is what does the trick.
worksheet.update('B1', "=A1 * 3", raw=False)

# Or if you prefer (row, col) notation
worksheet.update_cell(2, 1, 7)
worksheet.update_cell(2, 2, "=A2 * 3")
```

Will result in the following

[image: result]