# How to remove invisible apostrophe while using Python gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

The code below works. The problem I am encountering is an invisible `'` appears in the google sheet before all values in the first column '`problem`'.

I have attempted to change the formatting on the google sheet as described in other resources, but changing this string of ints to a number doesn't work.

I believe the issue is formatting while passing the values to Sheets, but there is nothing in the gspread docs that explain how to fix this.

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd

data=[['1, 2', 'hello', 4], ['3, 4', 'there', 3]]
cols = ['problem', 'words', 'ints']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
df_as_lists = df.values.tolist()

svc_acct = gspread.service_account_from_dict(info=gs_key)
sheet = svc_acct.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cW1ry2FwlEOGSF270skXLN52UeqWkhgFXfeDVqH_a3M/edit#gid=0')
wks = sheet.worksheet('Sheet1')
wks.update('A1:C3', df_as_lists)
```

Current values in Sheets:

```
  lists  words  ints
0  '1, 2  hello     4
1  '3, 4  there     3
```

Desired values in Sheets:

```
  lists  words  ints
0  1, 2  hello     4
1  3, 4  there     3
```

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648249/updating-cell-values-with-formulas-results-in-apostrophe-prefixes-with-sheets-ap, in short, add `raw=False` to toggle "user formatted data"